# How to handle failed to open stream error problem.?

Tags: php, dom, https, simple-html-dom

I Scrapped data from the website. But I fetched **Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request**  problem.

Here's the code:

```
$numOfPage = 2;
for ($i = 1; $i < $numOfPage; $i++) {
    $url = file_get_html('https://www.jugantor.com/all-news?page=' . '' . $i);
    foreach ($url->find('.col-8') as $a) {
        foreach ($a->find('a') as $b) {
            //echo $b->href . '<br>';
            $newsUrl[] = $b->href;
        }
    }
    $html = file_get_html($newsUrl[0]);
    foreach($html->find('.col-md-8') as $a){
        echo 1;
    }     
}
```

[image: Here is my output]

[image]

Comment: Is that your domain? If not, you need to contact the site and find out what they don't like about your URL.

Comment: I collect data from this URL. That's not my domain. but I try to scrap data from this URL

Comment: Are you able to open that URL in a browser?

Comment: yes. you can check this .  "https://www.jugantor.com/corporate-news/565519/সিলেটের-বন্যাদুর্গত-মানুষের-পাশে-স্বপ্ন"

Comment: I'm guessing that works in the browser, because the browser automatically applies URL encoding where it is missing. Either apply URL encoding to the path part after the numeric ID - or simply cut that off, because `https://www.jugantor.com/corporate-news/565519` appears to also work as URL for the same piece of content.